# Python - downloading a file over HTTP with progress bar and basic authentication

Tags: python, http, download

I'm using `urllib.urlretrieve` to download a file, and implementing a download progress bar using the `reporthook` parameter. Since `urlretrieve` doesn't directly support authentication, I came up with

```
import urllib

def urlretrieve_with_basic_auth(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None,
                                username="", password=""):
    class OpenerWithAuth(urllib.FancyURLopener):
        def prompt_user_passwd(self, host, realm):
            return username, password

    return OpenerWithAuth().retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
```

This works -- but it seems like there might be a more direct way to do this (maybe with urllib2 or httplib2 or...) --any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[urlgrabber](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/) has built-in support for progress bars, authentication, and more.

Comment: Ignacio's URI is now (2010-06-25) out of date, update one is [urlgrabber](http://linux.duke.edu/urlgrabber/)